# Show a message at specific times on a specific day

Tags: php, time

How can I insert a specific minute into the following to show a message:

```
if ($current_day == "Monday") {
if ($current_time >= 15 && $current_time <= 16) {
    echo "message";
}
}
```

For example I want "message" to show at 3:45 or 15:45 and not between the 15th and 16th hour.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show a message at exactly 3:45 AM and again at 3:45 PM, you could try this:

```
$current_day = date('l');
$current_time = date('G:i');

if ($current_day == "Monday") {
    if ($current_time == '03:45' || $current_time == '15:45') {
        echo "message";
    }
}
```

Or a little cleaner way (especially if you wanted to include a longer list of times):

```
if (date('l') == "Monday") {
    if (in_array(date('G:i'), array('03:45','15:45')) {
        echo "message";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** To specify a timezone, try inserting this line before either of the above pieces of code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Where 'America/Los_Angeles' could be any supported string representing your desired timezone from this page of the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: This would be according to the server time correct? The javascript code is universal, but I do want to hide my "messages" so they can't be seen. I was going to attempt embedding php inside my javascript code above.

Comment: I can't get these to work, my server's time is set to GMT and I made suer the times where correct.

Comment: Correct, this would use the server's time so all users would see it at the same moment no matter what their local time was. 

Also keep in mind that anything you put in JS is visible to users simply by viewing the page source.

I edited my original answer to include a way to change the timezone your server uses.

Comment: Awesome, this works great. I went with the first set because I decided to only use one time so I didn't need the array. Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it with javascript:

```
// Sunday is 0 Monday is 1 and so on
// January is 0 February is 1 and so on

var Digital=new Date()
var month=Digital.getUTCMonth()
var day=Digital.getUTCDate()
var year=Digital.getUTCFullYear()
var hours=Digital.getUTCHours()
var minutes=Digital.getUTCMinutes()

if (month==2&&day==16&&year==2015&&hours==01&&minutes==30 || hours==01&&minutes==45 || hours==01&&minutes==47)
document.write('<b>message here</b>')
else if (month==2&&day==17&&year==2015&&hours==01&&minutes==30 || hours==01&&minutes==45 || hours==01&&minutes==47)
document.write('<b>message 2 here</b>')
else
document.write('<b></b>')
```

Works perfectly no matter what timezone you're in. There's probably a less crazy way to do this but this is what I have so far.

Comment: Keep in mind that javascript gets the user's system time, so it is open to manipulation.

Comment: Okay, so if a user changes their system's time they can view the message?

Comment: What about if I used .getUTC that would prevent a user from being able to manipulate their time correct?

Comment: Anything you put in javascript will be visible in plain text to any user who takes the time to look for it .